# Collaborate best materials to one blog

Tags: seo, google

I want to copy all good materials from all differents web-sites (blogs) with not high-quality websites really to a new blog with expected good UX. How Google (and other Search Engines) will be relate to these blog with non-unique content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They won't like it at all. This is duplicate content and exactly what they do not want in their index.

Comment: I heard an opinion that Google prefer UX better than original content. Is it true?

Comment: Not even close to true. Content is king. But usability is still important.